# CertFindCertificateInStore fails to find certificate if the application launched with different user credentials

Tags: c++, security, certificate

I have certificates in my windows user certificates->Personal folder and its CA in Trusted Root folder.

I have a windows service application which tries to get the certificate using CertFindCertificateInStore() API.

```
HCERTSTORE hMy = CertOpenSystemStore(0, _T("MY"));
CString cert = _T("1.2.3.4");
PCCERT_CONTEXT context =  CertFindCertificateInStore( hMy, X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR, cert ,    NULL );
```

It is working fine if I run the service with current log in windows user credentials.

I created a local user (say TEST) and added to Administrator group. 
Also added to  LocayPolicies->User Rights Management->'Replace a process level tocken' and 'Logo on as service policies'.

I started the service with TEST user credentials. The service is started.
But the same code, CertFindCertificateInStore() API, fails to find the certificate and the API returns NULL.

I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I found the root cause. The personnel certificates of CURRENT_USER is not available to other user. I imported the certificates to LOCAL MACHINE and used below updated code to solve the issue.

```
HCERTSTORE hMy = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"MY");
```